# Odoo Configuration calculation - limit-request

Tags: config, odoo-15

Was configuring odoo-15 for a 4GB server.

4 * ((0.8*150) + (0.2*1024)) ~= 1.3GB(Allocating less than 50% system RAM for odoo)

```
[options]
limit_memory_hard = 1073741824
limit_memory_soft = 629145600
limit_time_cpu = 600
limit_time_real = 1200
max_cron_threads = 1
workers = 4
```

Now, looking at official documentation which they have done as example for 8GB

```
[options]
limit_memory_hard = 1677721600
limit_memory_soft = 629145600
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 600
limit_time_real = 1200
max_cron_threads = 1
workers = 8
```

My question: how `limit_request` is calculated ? And what is the role of it in server configuration? The application is e-commerce based with max of 10 concurrent users.
Also, if my other config is not okay for 4GB, let me know that too :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to not change any of the limits. If relay needed then only `limit_memory_hard` and limit_times.

Most of the limits are there for recycling old workers. Keeping the workers up for longer with more garbage is not helping anybody.

`limit_request = 8192`  means it is recycling worker after it is served 8192 requests.